# How to set two images with link inline

Tags: css, image

I would like to set two images inline with `CSS`, but the `CSS` should be in the HTML element, not in a separate `style.css` file.

**Like this :**

```
<ul style="display: inline">
<li>image</li>
<li>image</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to add more images on this page http://www.top20broker.com/eco-calender/ beside the video corner image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set two images in one line you can do it as follows:

```
<div style="display:inline"><img src="pic1.jpg" /></div>
<div style="display:inline"><img src="pic2.jpg" /></div>
```

The first image should be rapped in a div element with display: inline.

Answer (score 0):

if what you need is to have two images side by side in the same line, if the container is large enough you shouldn't need any special code because IMG tags work like an inline-block element.

```html
    <img src='http://placehold.it/250x130'>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/250x140'>
```